# Index object in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a dictionary containing a lot of fields, and if possible I would like to index it as it is inside ElasticSearch. I am using Python for this. Could it work or is it a limitation of ElasticSearch that it can support only simple data types? Thanks!

Later edit: My dictionary looks like below:

```
  {
      'lingpipe': Tagging(tagger_id = 'lingpipe', raw_tagging = '', tagger_config = None, tagger_version = None, generation_time = StreamTime(epoch_ticks = 1364699587.0, zulu_timestamp = '2013-03-31T04:13:07.663542Z')),
      'serif': Tagging(tagger_id = 'serif', raw_tagging = '', tagger_config = 'English', tagger_version = '6.1', generation_time = None),
      'stanford': Tagging(tagger_id = 'stanford', raw_tagging = '1\tFree\tFree\tNNP\tO\t23\t27\n2\tBiscayne\tBiscayne\tNNP\tO\t28\t36\n3\tNational\tNational\tNNP\tO\t37\t45\n4\tPark\tPark\tNNP\tO\t46\t50\n5\tGuide\tGuide\tNNP\tO\t51\t56\n6\tGet\tget\tVB\tO\t57\t60\n7\tyour\tyou\tPRP$\tO\t61\t65\n8\tquick\tquick\tJJ\tO\t66\t71\n9\tguide\tguide\tNN\tO\t72\t77\n10\tto\tto\tTO\tO\t78\t80\n11\tthe\tthe\tDT\tO\t81\t84\n12\ttop\ttop\tJJ\tO\t85\t88\n13\thotels\thotel\tNNS\tO\t89\t95\n14\t,\t,\t,\tO\t95\t96\n15\trestaurants\trestaurant\tNNS\tO\t97\t108\n16\tand\tand\tCC\tO\t109\t112\n17\tthings\tthing\tNNS\tO\t113\t119\n18\tto\tto\tTO\tO\t120\t122\n19\tdo\tdo\tVB\tO\t123\t125\n20\t.\t.\t.\tO\t125\t126\n\n1\tGrab\tgrab\tVB\tO\t127\t131\n2\tit\tit\tPRP\tO\t132\t134\n3\tand\tand\tCC\tO\t135\t138\n4\tGo\tgo\tVB\tO\t139\t141\n5\t!\t!\t.\tO\t141\t142', tagger_config = 'annotators: {tokenize, cleanxml, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner}, properties: pos.maxlen=100', tagger_version = 'Stanford CoreNLP ver 1.2.0', generation_time = StreamTime(epoch_ticks = 1338505200.0, zulu_timestamp = '2012-06-01T00:00:00.0Z'))
  }
```

so it's basically a mix of data types. I am not yet sure how I can serialize it, ES is throwing a Serialization error. How can I convert this object to JSON?

Comment: What do you mean "simple data types"? ElasticSearch can store multiple fields in a single object, all of them quite searchable as a collection, etc. A Dictionary with lots of fields is quite a simple concept for that matter.

Comment: By simple data fields I mean only string, integer, float, double, long, boolean, date, and geo_point. http://exploringelasticsearch.com/modeling_data.html

Comment: See how you can do arrays and objects in that same link? That should achieve what you need, no? "Complex JSON types are also supported by elasticsearch, using both arrays and object notation. Additionally, elasticsearch documents can handle more complex relations, such as parent/child relationships, and a special nested document type."

Comment: So probably I won't be able: "An important thing to remember, however, is that elasticsearch arrays cannot store mixed types." My dictionary is made up of different types of data.

Comment: That's what objects are for.

Comment: I am not sure how I can serialize it. Basically ES is throwing me a serialization error.

Comment: Please show us the error you're getting.